# LXC container cannot communicate with other devices over Bridge Interface

Tags: linux, networking, containers, lxc

1. I have a VM hosting linux os.
2. I have an LXC container running inside of the VM.
3. The VM has 3 bridge interfaces supplied as adapters.
4. The LXC container is 3 interfaces configured in bridge mode (veth) as shown below

```
## t3_br0
lxc.net.13.type = veth
lxc.net.13.link = t3_br0
lxc.net.13.name = eth1
lxc.net.13.ipv4.address = 10.x.x.xxx/24
lxc.net.13.flags = up

## t2_br0
lxc.net.14.type = veth
lxc.net.14.link = t2_br0
lxc.net.14.name = eth2
lxc.net.14.ipv4.address = 142.x.x.xxx/24
lxc.net.14.flags = up

## t1_br0
lxc.net.15.type = veth
lxc.net.15.link = t1_br0
lxc.net.15.name = eth3
lxc.net.15.ipv4.address = 192.x.x.xxx/24
lxc.net.15.flags = up
```

I am able to ping other devices on my network on each of the respective bridge interfaces from the VM but not from within my linux container within the VM even with veth and using a bridge in config. I am however able to receive traffic on all of these interfaces, within the container. I'm stuck on trying to figure out why i cant ping these other network devices on their respective interfaces while using bridged interfaces for the linux container.